# build email client in dashboard

Tags: php, email

I was wondering, how hard would it be to create a custom webmail client in a client area dashboard? This can be done if it has to connect to one server. But in this setup we're talking about 7 mail servers.

I was thinking about letting an email client make an IMAP connection with php based upon the client's domain name after the @ and the user's password. I haven't tried it yet, I wanted to hear some opinions about this. What are the best php mail client scripts around nowdays? Will this idea work? How hard will it be?